# enable screen rotation android

Tags: java, android, rotation, orientation

I have disabled screen rotation in one activity in particular time. Now I need that particular time it will be enabled. How can I enable rotation, when i disabled it [using this:](http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/solved-set-screen-orientation-programmatically/)  ?

Comment: The content of that link was deleted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

See [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND) for more details

Comment: this got me going in the right direction for supporting only the dual portrait modes, thanks! `ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR`

Answer (score 3):

put this line in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and use this code as per your requirement

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and also put this to enable

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

Comment: "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED" is incorrect it's will be "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED"

Answer (score 3):

Check out also that you don't have this line in your manifest file for your activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

That will disable the rotate of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);` is **incorrect**

If you want to enable rotation again you have to use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable rotation again, simply use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```